# When mirroring the screen on a Mac to AppleTV, can the Mac built-in monitor be shut off?

Tags: macos, appletv, streaming

Is there a way to, when mirroring the screen on a Mac to AppleTV, to have the Mac built-in monitor shut off?
It is a waste of energy to have both monitors on when I'm watching a movie.

(If it's relevant, I have a Macbook Pro with an M2 Pro chip).

Comment: Try setting the AppleTV as a separate Display (turn off mirroring), connect power, mouse, and keyboard, then close the lid (closed clamshell mode).  I can’t test at the moment as where I am currently, I don’t have an AppleTV or something I can stream to.

Comment: @Allan, that should work, indeed. I would need to have an external keyboard/mouse, as you mentioned...
But maybe there's no other way...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to make shortcuts to allow the lid to close without the power turning off. First set the Apple TV to *mirror* the display.

Then open Shortcuts. Make a new shortcut and call it "Apple TV Movie On". Add a "Run AppleScript" block containing:

```
set thePassword to "yourpassword"

do shell script "sudo pmset -b sleep 0; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 1" password thePassword with administrator privileges
```

Replace *yourpassword* with your admin password.

Now make another shortcut titled "Apple TV Movie Off" and add the AppleScript block. Change the code to:

```
set thePassword to "yourpassword"

do shell script "sudo pmset -b sleep 0; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 1" password thePassword with administrator privileges
```

Again, replace *yourpassword* with your admin password.

Now drag the two shortcuts into the "Menu Bar" folder in the sidebar in Shortcuts. The shortcuts logo should appear in your menu bar. If it doesn't, press Cmd-, in Shortcuts, go to the Sidebar tab and make sure menu bar is checked.

Now when you run "Apple TV Movie On" and close the lid, the display will turn off but it will continue AirPlaying to the Apple TV. After you have finished, run "Apple TV Movie Off".

Comment: Nice suggestion. Thanks. 
By the way, because I need many times to access the mouse to pause/play the movie... Is there a way to turn off the built-in monitor, without having to close the laptop lid?

Comment: Of course! Just run the shortcut, and then turn down the brightness to minimum, leaving the lid open.